# How to build a "file copy" RPM using cmake?

Tags: cmake, rpm, rpmbuild, cpack

I want to build a demo rpm package which copies one file to the target system and executes some pre and post script.
I managed to create a package. When I run the package on the target system I got the e warning "warning: package xxx intend for yyy plattform". But no file was copied.
Any ideas?
After goes my code/project:

Project tree:

```
myRpm/CMakeLists.txt
myRpm/install.txt
myRpm/post.py
myRpm/post.sh
myRpm/pre.py
myRpm/pre.sh
```

CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CPack.cmake")
    INCLUDE(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
    set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL_IN_ONE_PACKAGE 1)
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "my test")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "tets")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "fake rpm")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "6.6.6")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "6")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "6")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "6")
    set(targetDestDir "myDir")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
    install(
        FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/install.txt" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pre.py" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/post.py"
        DESTINATION "${targetDestDir}"
    )
    set(CPACK_RPM_PRE_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pre.sh")
    set(CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/post.sh")
    include(CPack)
endif()
```

Comment: Which *host* machine (where you build project and pack it) and *target* machine (where you extract package) you use? (Architecture, OS).

Comment: I build the rpm on a Debian running in a VM. The target is a ARM system. It is build with the help of the Yocto toolchain.

Comment: @ARM: Linux sama5d3xek 4.1.0-linux4sam_5.3-00046-g19291d7 #1 Wed Jun 1 16:17:37 CEST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux (given by uname -a)

Comment: @VM: Linux Dev 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux (given by uname -a)

Comment: seems that I have to set the "CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE" to "noarch". It is not set by [default](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackRPM.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE is important when building RPMs for other systems/distros.
The following code should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CPack.cmake")
    INCLUDE(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_TMPDIR /tmp CACHE PATH "Output dir for tmp")
    set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL_IN_ONE_PACKAGE 1)
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "mytest")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "tets")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "fake rpm")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "6.6.6")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "6")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "6")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "6")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
    set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "noarch")
    set(targetDestDir ${CMAKE_INSTALL_TMPDIR})
    install(
        FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/install.txt" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/post.py"
        DESTINATION "${targetDestDir}"
    )
    set(CPACK_RPM_PRE_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pre.sh")
    set(CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/post.sh")
    include(CPack)
endif()
```

Note:
the pre.sh and post.sh are in the root dir of the sources. In the post.sh the post.py is called.